# A script runs via localhost but not via 127.0.0.1

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, ubuntu-16.04, apache2, cgi

I am trying to migrate some software from apache 2.2 to 2.4. I have it working - almost. When accessing the server via address `localhost` things work, but when trying to access via `127.0.0.1` some things don't.

For example, **http://localhost/cgi-bin/WI_facility** shows me the correct page, but **http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/WI_facility**  asks me do I want to `save the file WI_facility which is BIN file (164KB)`.

Key part of the apache2.conf is below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
    <Directory /var/www/cgi-bin>
        AllowOverride All
        Options +ExecCGI
        SetHandler cgi-script
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Edit: I forgot to mention this is on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>` does not help - I still get the download question.

Comment: Interestingly, the same configuration works with Ubuntu 17.10.